# Are different "roles" supported for the new TableView in QtQuick Controls 2

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

The new TableView with Qt Quick Controls 2 seems to work very fast (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-tableview.html). But the demo code is only based on simple strings. I would like to implement a TableView which can display (via delegate) different gui elemets. Example: (Q)Image, Text, TextInput, special Gui element, Text, and so far.
My Understanding to distinguish between these "display" things is to use the "roles" in the Qt context.
The above example shows only the "role" {Qt::DisplayRole, "display"}. What about custom roles?
How can I display them? How I have to change the "delegate" in the TableView?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: you can use any role foo via `model.foo` if you add a respective entry in `roleNames()` (`{FooRole, "foo"}`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two interessting youtube videos about this topic:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-GOfY1kEP2A
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oV3aguIZLfg
The first one goes into my direction. It seems the solution is the DelegateChooser.
Unfortunately the "Process" code is quite complex. So I simplified it. You can see my first simple project about this under https://github.com/tlaemmlein/TableViewQtQuick2Examples, which is based on Shawn Rutledge code.
Thanks.